# oracle 9 when not exist else

Tags: oracle, null, case

I have these codes:

```
select case 
     when exists (select 1 
                  from table1
                  where id=608071) 
     then column1 
     else 0
  end as abc
from table1 where id=608071;
```

and

```
select decode(count(column1), 0, column1) abc
from (select column1
      from table1
      where id=608071) group by column1;
```

and none of them returns me no column1, no 0, no error. It gives me null, i.e. nothing. No rows return. I need to get 0 when particular id does not exist. What is wrong in here?

Comment: probably there is no `id=608071`

Comment: Yes, there is no id=608071, but in that case I need to get 0.

Comment: I did this and it worked: select case when exists (select 1 from table1 where id=608071) then (select column1 from table1 where id=608071)
            else 0
        end from dual

Answer (score 1):

try this!!

```
select case when exists (select 1 from table1 where id= '608071')  then  (select column1 from table1)  else '0' end as abc from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your requirement: "I need to get 0 when particular id does not exist"

```
select
  nvl(T.COLUMN1, 0) COLUMN1_OR_ZERO
from
  DUAL D left join(
    select
      *
    from
      TABLE1
    where
      id = '608071') T on (1=1)
```

With this query, you only scan the table once.